# Preventing data loss in client authoritative database writes

Tags: algorithm

A project I'm working on requires users to insert themselves into a list on a server. We expect a few hundred users over a weekend and while very unlikely, a collision could happen in which two users submit the list concurrently and one of them is lost. The server has no validation, it simply allows you to get and put data.

I was pointed in the direction of "optimistic locking" but I'm having trouble grasping when exactly the data should be validated and how it prevents this from happening. If one of the clients reads the data, adds itself and then checks again to ensure that the data is the same with the use of an index or timestamp, how does this prevent the other client from doing the same and then one overwriting the other?

I'm trying to understand the flow in the context of two clients getting data and putting data.

Comment: Please refrain from answers involving not letting the client be authoritative. This is purely for a prototype phase of a project.

Comment: @Henry how exactly?

Answer (score 0):

The point of optimistic locking is that the decision to accept or reject a write is taken on the server, and is protected against concurrency by a pessimistic transaction or some sort of hardware protection, such as compare-and-swap. So a client requests a write together with some sort of timestamp or version identifier, and the server only accepts the write if the timestamp is still accurate. If it isn't the client gets some sort of rejection code and will have to try again. If it is, the client gets told that its write succeeded.

This is not the only way to handle receiving data from multiple clients. One popular alternative is to use a reliable messaging system - for example the Java Messaging Service specifies an interface for such systems for which you can find open source implementations. Clients write into the messaging system and can go away as soon as their message is accepted. The server reads requests from the messaging system and acts on them. If the server or the network goes down it's no big deal: the messages will still be there to be read when they come back (typically they are written to disk and have the same level of protection as database data although if you look at a reliable message queue implementation you may find that it is not, in fact, built on top of a standard database table).

One example of a writeup of the details of optimistic locking is the HTTP server Etag specification e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_ETag